# Android Change widget button

Tags: android, android-widget

i've created my first widget but i've a problem when i change the button image.
below it's a part of code of java file for widget:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
if (mp == null){
 mp = MediaPlayer.create(context.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.segno);
}

final String action = intent.getAction();

if (ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER.equals(action)) {
  if (mp.isPlaying()){
           mp.stop();
           mp.release();
           mp = MediaPlayer.create(context.getApplicationContext(), R.raw.segno);
  }
  else{
               RemoteViews control = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
               control.setImageViewResource(R.id.button, R.drawable.pausa);

               ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(context, Widget.class);
               AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(cn, control);

               mp.start();

  }
  super.onReceive(context, intent);
 }
  super.onReceive(context, intent);
}
```

I read in the log this:

```
02-17 23:46:57.042: W/AppWidgetHostView(946): updateAppWidget couldn't find any view, using error view
```

I think this is a problem but i don't understand how resolve it.
when appear this error the widget say: Problem loading widget.

Thank you all

This is a XML Layout for widget

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:layout_margin="4dp">

<Button
   android:id="@+id/button"
   android:paddingRight="30dp"
   android:layout_width="50dp"
   android:layout_height="50dp"
   android:background="@drawable/vai" />

<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/imageView1"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
   android:maxHeight="100dp"
   android:maxWidth="100dp"
   android:src="@drawable/segno" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you add the widget layout?

Comment: sure! added layout of widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to change the image of a `Button` which doesn't have the properties of `Button` according to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RemoteViews.html) `setImageViewResource` is equivilant to `ImageView` properties so Instead of having a button I suggest you change it either to `ImageButton` or to `ImageView` that is clickable.

so maybe your XML will look like this:

```
<ImageButton
  android:id="@+id/button"
  android:paddingRight="30dp"
  android:layout_width="50dp"
  android:layout_height="50dp"
  android:background="@drawable/vai" />
```

**Update**

the reason is that `android:background` is different than `android:src` it doesn't resize the photo it actually make the image as size of the photo (setImageViewResource is same as src) .. so you have either to resize the photo from the beginning or try to add this attribute to your `ImageButton`

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

but I am not sure it will work, haven't tried it.

hope this works for you. try it out and give me a feedback.

Comment: cool!! it works!!!! thank you!!! now the problem is: when the image change the size of new image are wrong.

Comment: please check the updated part. if you found my answer useful, I hope you tick my answer as right.

Comment: ops, sorry. i'm new to stackoverflow :P

Comment: glad I could help and welcome to StackOverFlow ;) happy programming